# Qt mac release misses frameworks

Tags: c++, macos, qt, frameworks, cmake

I wanna release a version of my Qt project. I am using Qt 5.2.0 and OSX 10.9. So far I have an app file but it still has some dependencies and you cannot execute it, unless with user `nik`.

When I execute `otool -L MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` I get this back:

```
/Users/nik/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
/Users/nik/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
/Users/nik/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1056.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

How can I include those dependencies in my build? The stuff under `/System/` and `/usr/` should be available on all macs, right? So I only need to include those Qt Frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the frameworks into your app bundle and change the links to the Qt frameworks. OSX has a development tool called install_name_tool which allows you to manually change the references.

Fortunately, Qt provides a command line tool macdeployqt, which will copy the required Qt frameworks and change the references for you.

You can read about it in the Qt docs for [deploying a Qt application for OSX](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html). It's very simple to use. Assuming your path is setup to include the Qt tools just call this from the path to your application: -

```
macdeployqt MyApp.app
```

If you use other, non-Qt frameworks, you'll have to manually copy them and use install_name_tool for those.

Comment: I do not have `macdeployqt`. I also do not have the environment variable `$QTDIR`. Thats weird. How can I set this variable or execute the command?

Comment: If you have Qt installed, you will have macdeployqt. It's in a folder in the Qt installation called 'bin'. If you don't have it in your path, you can put the full path to the executable. Mine is at Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/bin

Comment: That's super weird, I added `$QTDIR` with the export command and it still does not recognize macdeployqt. Eventually, it worked with the absolute path. Thanks a lot! You saved my day.